# Windows 7 not saving settings

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-profile, settings

I am using Windows Server 2008 and I created a Windows 7 user. I have installed all software on my Windows 7 computer, but when I restart Windows 7 it reverts to its previous state without saving my new settings.

For example, I put the My Computer and Network Places icons on the Windows 7 Desktop and installed some software, but when I restart all icons disappear and only the Recycle Bin is there.

I think Windows 7 is not saving settings and considering me as a new user and first time login. How can I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like a possible temporary profile issue. Couple questions. A) Is your user account a domain level account or a local account? 
B) Is your 2008 Server a domain controller applying any GPO's or is the windows 7 machine keeping control of its own security settings?

Comment: Something else you may want to check is if the user you configured the desktop with is in the "Guest" group. Is it?

Comment: If this is an AD environment, do you have mandatory profiles in place?